Easiest way for non-programmers to add my script to QGIS
QGIS 3.36.2, Python 3.12.3
I've got a script (about 500 lines of code) that I add to my project and test with the "Open Existing Script" button of the Processing Toolbar (it's not formatted as a processing script, so there's a warning every time). This script does the following:

Pressing the green "Run Script" button opens a popup to request a server URL.
Creates a toolbar with a "start" and a "stop" button.
Pressing the "start" button opens a popup in which the user has to enter some data.
A layer is created and a timer is started that connects to a server periodically and draws a feature on that layer using the input data (the old feature is always removed beforehand).
The "stop" button stops the timer. Clicking on "start" starts at 3. again.
If there's an error, then the timer is stopped and a popup is displayed.

It currently looks like this:
#Imports here
class MyScript:
    def __init__(self):
        #Some code that does 1.+2.
    #More functions that call other functions and do 3.-6.
mc = MyClass()

What's the easiest way for other users, who haven't got any programming experience and just want to use QGIS, to add my script to their project?
Requirements:

This script must NOT run automatically when QGIS is started. If the user wants to run the script, then they should have to press a button, similar to "Run Script" (but without the warning).
The script also must NOT attach itself to a specific project. It has to be available for any project the user opens but should not be saved in it.
The script has to be removable.

I know that you can "Add Script to Toolbox" and remove it again by deleting the file in QGIS' folder in AppData\Roaming. I would probably be able to prevent the automatic running by adding another button that calls 1., instead of doing that in __init__, but afaik my script would have to be a "processing script" to be added to the toolbox and you aren't supposed to do a lot of things with those (e.g. do your own error handling and show a QMessageBox or access the GUI), according to the docs. I don't want the users to have to deal with the "seems there is no valid script in the file" warning either. What's the alternative?

is there are reason not to wrap this up as a processing script and publish it as pluigin

or you can just make you script as plugin (without wraping as prcessing). Plugins can be added easy, and plugin is pass to other your requirements. And thats pretty easy to do for you as programmer

@IanTurton I don't want to do do it as a processing script because, according to the docs, it's highly recommended not to access the GUI or handle errors yourself but I have to do at least the first thing because the user has to input data for my script to work, and it makes my life easier to just reuse the message box for errors. Haven't tested the processing script yet but it also looks like you have to add quite a bit of code just to make it that.

@Dezmonder How are plugins loaded exactly? Do they run the same way processing scripts do, just without the extra code that makes a ps a ps? Do I have to publish the plugin publicly for my users to use them or is it possible for them to just plop the file into a specific folder and it'll work right off the bat?

You can make your script as plugin. By plugin "Plugin Builder 3" you can create a base for you plugin (and i higly reccomend you to use "plugin reloader" for you debuging). On QGIS start, plugins initializes with auto-generated file (if you will use builder), after initialization your plugin icon will be added to toolbar. Afer user clicks on icon, plugin runs.
You'll need to add some code, but realy not much.
You users can just drop plugin folder in QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins, restart QGIS and turn plugin on in "modules" menu. If user needs to update plugin, then just rewrite old folder with new and restart plugin in modules menu (or restart QGIS)
UPD:
As @user2856 mentioned, user can install plugins from ZIP archive.
And as remembered, you can set your repo so users can auto-update plugin. In post written about startup.py script, but i think at current QGIS versions, update procces made easier.

That sounds promising! Is it really that easy? Just give the user a folder they copy into their "plugin" folder? That would certainly also make it easier to distribute the icons for my buttons. And on my side, set it up like this (there's a link to a github project with a good explanation): Add the four functions and move my code from __init__ to run?

@Neph yep, thats really easy. As I see your code, i reccomend not move code from __init__ to run, but call your class in run. And don't forget about metadata.txt, it is really important

I just noticed and fixed a small mistake in my question: My __init__ does both 1. (opens popup to request url) and 2. (creates buttons), not just 2., and should only run once the user actively clicks on some kind of button. For me that's currently the green "play" button in the processing script editor. From the looks of it, the QAction that is created in initGui in the other answer and calls run (does it have to be named "run"?) replaces that green button, correct?

Even easier is to provide users with a zip file of your plugin. Then in the QGIS Plugin window, click "Install from ZIP".

@user2856 That's awesome, thanks! I'm going to test everything within the next couple of days.

I haven't tested "Install from ZIP" yet but successfully added my code as a plugin. It only required minimal changes (described here), the Plugin Builder isn't necessary, but careful, afterwards the script won't run with "Open Existing Script" anymore. You don't have to restart QGIS to test a new version, just delete the __pycache__ folder inside your plugin's folder and reload the plugin (untick and tick again).

@Neph try using "plugin reloader". It makes testing new virsion easier (just push button)

Thanks for the recommendation! You don't also happen to know a way to "dock" the "Plugins | Installed" window, like the Processing Toolbox (I also have to unload the plugin to test things, not just reload it), do you?

@Neph I don't using processing toolbox, so i don't know how it looks like.
But as i see, modules window is modal dialog, so you can't work with other QGIS windows, until you close modal window

The Processing Toolbox is docked to the right of the main area in QGIS (similar to the Browser and Layers on the left), which makes it easy to access both at the same time, while the "Plugins" window makes it impossible to access anything below it. That's a pity.

Changing the path to the default script folder in the options for every user to a central location gives you easy control over which scripts are available, as well as the users easy access via the toolbox. You could change the path by providing a default user profile.

Not sure how that answers my question. I've got a single script that I want to give to certain people. They're in control of their own QGIS install, I must not mess with that or their current projects in any way.

So you save the script so said new default folder and everyone who changed their default folder has access via the tool-box. That definitely is a solution @Neph

Are you talking about a processing script? I don't have access to the users' PCs and I or my script also must not mess with their QGIS install in any way. The user needs full control and has to be able to use my script with their current projects (and whatever other plugins that they're already using and that I don't know of).

You don't need to. They change their default path to a central location everyone has access to, done.

I still don't quite understand why that would help in my case: If users have to change their QGIS install's default path to a "central location", that would not only require everyone to be in the same network but would also make it impossible for anyone to use their own plugins. Correct?
